# How to find the reaction rate in an enzyme reaction?

Tags: biochemistry, enzymes, enzyme-kinetics

First time posting questions here, so let me know if I need to edit anything.

I need to decide $dC/dt$ and $dP/dt$ when the reaction is like this, where I only know we must have 2 substrates $S$ to react with the enzyme $E$ at the same time:

$$2S + E \overset{k_a}{\longrightarrow} C \overset{k_c}{\longrightarrow} 2P + E, \quad C \overset{k_b}{\longrightarrow} 2S + E$$

Is $dC/dt = 2k_a SE - (k_b + k_c)C$? Is $dP/dt = 2k_cC$? Thanks in advance.

Edit: alright, so $dC/dt$ should be $k_a S^2 E - (k_b + k_c)C$, right? Now suppose I take $E_0 = E + C$ to be the total enzyme concentration, and transform $dC/dt$ as $$dC/dt = k_a E_0 S^2 - (k_a S^2 + k_b + k_c) C.$$ By quasi-equilibrium approximation, let $$dC/dt = 0 \Rightarrow C = (k_a E_0 S^2)/(k_a S^2 + k_b + k_c).$$ Then in this equilibrium, $$dP/dt = 2k_bC = (2k_a k_b E_0 S^2)/ (k_a S^2 + k_b + k_c).$$ So if we want to find out $V_m$ and $K_m$ s.t. $$\lim_{S \to \infty} dP/dt = V_m, \quad dP(S = K_m)/dt = V_m/2,$$ then we would need $V_m = 2 k_b E_0, K_m = \sqrt{(k_b + k_c)/(k_a)}$. Any mistakes so far?

Comment: This is very close to the Michaelis-Menten scheme. The rate equations are ok, you now need  to assume that C is  at steady state dC/dt=0 and solve the equation for C. Look up the MM scheme for how to do this if you are not sure.

Comment: Sure thanks. May I also confirm that $V_m$ and $K_m$ in this case would be $2k_c E_0$ and $(k_b + k_c)/(2k_a)$ respectively? $E_0$ is the total enzyme concentration which is assumed to be constant.

Comment: IMO one of the best derivations of the Michaelis-Menten equation, together with a lucid explanation of why the steady-state hypothesis is superior to the 'equilibrium' assumption of Michaelis and Menten, is given by Haldane (1930) in his book 'Enzymes'.  The first chapter of his book is available [here](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/Pharmacology/dc-bits/haldane-enzymes-1930-s.pdf), made available through [DC's Improbable Science](http://www.dcscience.net/).  (See also [here](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/Pharmacology/dc-bits/chpapers.html)).

Comment: I did not notice  before (sorry) but you should have $dC/dt=k_aS^2E-(k_b+k_c)C=0$ at steady state.

Comment: @tomd I don't have any more info about any $k$ or any substances in this problem. How is it now?

Comment: dC/dt is surely equal to `kaEo[S][S]−(kb+kc)C`, and this is where one of the difficulties of treating what essentially is a two-substrate mechanism as a single substrate mechanism arise? [Modified comment: thanks to @porphyrin]

Comment: It looks good to me. (It is probably worth pointing out that you are assuming (I think) the formation of a ternary complex between enz and two S (in the nomenclature of Cleland, an ordered Bi-Bi mechanism where both substrates are the same? This might not be the case: the enz _could_ bind one S, do something to it producing a modified enz, take on board another S where the modified enz does something different to the second S to bind - in the nomen. of Cleland a 'ping-pong' mechanism (but I know of no examples where both substrates are the same!), and a different rate law will apply).

Comment: One further thought (and you probably know all about this): If the steady-state hypothesis is assumed, the initial rate (in the forward direction, say) for the ordered Bi-Bi mechanism _cannot_ be defined in terms of just Km and Vmax values. One must define one other kinetic constant (this is not true if the equilibr. assumption is made). [Dalziel](http://www.actachemscand.org/pdf/acta_vol_11_p1706-1723.pdf) calls this phiAB (or phi12), and it has dimensions of a reciprocal third-order rate constant. Other authors (including Cleland) call it something like KiA KmB. This _might_ be a difficulty?

Comment: @tomd just confirmed the reaction forms a ternary complex instead of 1S-E complex first

Comment: Problem solved. Should I close this question or...?